# How to encrypt and decrypt passwords for selenium testing?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, selenium

The context is testing of a web app with selenium while using a number of virtual user accounts we created for this very purpose.  And so the testing process needs to access our sites and log-on with the virtual user's id and password.

None of these accounts are critical and they are flagged as testing accounts so no damage can be done.  Still, it would probably be a good idea to encrypt the passwords and decrypt them prior to use.

If it matter, our test app is written in Python, Django and uses PostgreSQL for the database.  It runs on a small Linode instance.

What might best practices be for something like this?

**EDIT 1**

The other thought I had was to store the credentials on a second machine and access them through and API while only allowing that access to happen from a known server's non-public IP.  In other words, get two instances at Linode and create a private machine-to-machine connection within the data center.

In this scenario, access to the first machine would allow someone to potentially make requests to the second machine if they are able to de-obfuscate the API code.  If someone really wants the data they can certainly get it.

We could add two factor authentication as a way to gate the tests.  In other words, even if you had our unencrypted test_users table you couldn't do anything with them because of the 2FA mechanism in place just for these users.

Being that this is for testing purposes only I am starting to think the best solution might very well be to populate the `test_users` table with valid passwords only while running a test.  We could keep the data safe elsewhere and have a script that uploads the data to the test server when we want to run a test suite.  Someone with access to this table could not do thing with it because all  the passwords would be invalid.  In fact, we could probably use this fact to detect such a breach.

I just hate the idea of storing unencrypted passwords even if it is for test users that can't really do any damage to the actual app (their transactions being virtual).

**EDIT 2**

An improvement to that would be to go ahead and encrypt the data and keep it in the test server.  However, every time the tests are run the system would reach out to us for the crypto key.  And, perhaps, after the test is run the data is re-encrypted with a new key.  A little convoluted but it would allow for encrypted passwords (and even user id's, just to make it harder) on the test server.  The all-important key would be nowhere near the server and it would self-destruct after each use.

Answer (score 0):

What is generally done in a case like this is to put the password through a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), and store the hashed password.

To verify a login, hash the provided password and compare the calculated hash to the stored version.

The idea behind this is that it is considered impossible to reverse a good cryptographic hash function. So it doesn't matter if an attacker could read the hashed passwords.

Example in Python3:

```
In [1]: import hashlib

In [2]: hashlib.sha256('This is a test'.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
Out[2]: 'c7be1ed902fb8dd4d48997c6452f5d7e509fbcdbe2808b16bcf4edce4c07d14e'

In [3]: hashlib.sha256('This is a tist'.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
Out[3]: 'f80b4162fc28f1f67d1a566da60c6c5c165838a209e89f590986333d62162cba'

In [4]: hashlib.sha256('This is a tst.'.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
Out[4]: '1133d07c24ef5f46196ff70026b68c4fa703d25a9f12405ff5384044db4e2adf'
```

(for Python2, just leave out the `encode`.)

As you can see, even one-letter changes lead to a big change in the hash value.

Comment: The intent here isn't to hash the pwd and then just compare hashes.  I need to actually use the plain-text passwords for automated load testing with selenium.  In that context our test tool would retrieve user id and password and use them to log on to our site using one of our test users.  I am simply exploring the idea of encrypting the passwords rather than storing them in the database as plain text.  I understand the exercise might be futile but I have to at least give it some thought.  Someone suggested storing the key or crypto passphrase as an enviroment variable in the OS.

Comment: hashing is good for most purposes but unfortunately for selenium testing a real password has to be entered into the password field

Comment: @martin's Under the assumption that a hypothetical attacker has access to the machine where the password is stored, you can only slow the attacker down.

Comment: @RolandSmith, see my edit.  You are right.  Not sure there's a real solution to this issue.

Comment: @martin's I wouldn't worry too much about the test passwords. If the attacker has access to the database, your security has aleady been broken.